# Do these sentences have differences;

Tags: prepositions

> 1- There is a guy below window
>   2- There is a guy below of window

I want to learn the differences between aforementioned sentences. Are there even differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your sentences are UNgrammatical.

The first requires an article (either **a** or **the**) before window. We do not talk about **window** without introducing the word with an article.

The second needs to lose the preposition **of**. It is NOT correct to talk about things being **below of** something. They are simply **below** something.

(An exception might be a construction such as: **No, the steps are not above the ground; they are below, of course.** but it's highly unusual.)

So you need to rewrite your sentence/s as follows:

> There is a guy below a/the window.

In reality, we are far more likely to speak about **below the window** than **below a window**.